# What is the name of the operator $() in a shell?

Tags: shell

What is the name of the operator `$()` in a Shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called command substitution. From [`man bash`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution):

> **Command Substitution**
>   Command substitution allows the output of a command to replace the command name. There are two forms:
>
> ```
> $(command)
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> `command`
> ```

Comment: Thank you for the URL, just started looking for it. :)

Comment: Thanks! So `$()` is called the `Command substitution operator` and `\`\`` as well?

Comment: Yes, in the end they're different syntax for the same thing.